# Insert into sqlite3 DB in JS, nothing added to table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

My table structure :

```
sqlite3 <<< '.dump' bdd.sqlite
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE stats (epoch INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, scenario TEXT, image_path TEXT, exec_time INTEGER, result TEXT, passed TEXT);
COMMIT;
```

My javascript code :

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./bdd.sqlite');
db.run(`INSERT INTO stats VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)`, [ Date.now(), 'foobar', 'none', 'OK', '', 'passed OK' ], function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err.message);
  }
  // get the last insert id
  console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
});
db.close();
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

When I run the `nodejs` script, nothing is added nor error

Comment: Corrected number of arguments, still the same issue

Comment: Does it work in the REPL? Assuming you are getting  NO feedback in the console (either error or success), my gut says `require` is failing and bailing because of "pathing" to the sqlite3 module. Your code worked (for me) in the REPL. Alternatively, it worked from WIndows cmd `> node /full/path/to/script` with _full path to sqlite3 module_

Comment: Damn, it works in REPL but not as script, and despite `.verbose()` I don't get messages like in REPL. Adedd full path to sqlite.js and run the script with full path

Comment: Added bug report https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/1140

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, don't use this #*!% `npm-sqlite3` module, but `npm-better-sqlite3`.

Some modules on `npm` seems really crappy.

So what I wrote to do the things works with [better-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3) :

```
const db = require('better-sqlite3')('bdd.sqlite');

const stmt = db.prepare('INSERT INTO stats VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
const info = stmt.run(Date.now(), 'relais', 'none', 'OK', '', 'passed OK');

console.log(info.changes); // => 1
```